# Position of more than one prepositions in sentence

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

I am a bit confused that how to place the preposition "for".

> 1. I took some apples for you from India.
> 2. I took some apples from India for you.

The placement of "for you" is correct in which sentences?

Answer (score 1):

As an English speaker, both are grammatically correct and it doesn't matter where you put the "for" but the second one sounds nicer.

Comment: Thanks D manokhin, 1. I got some Books from India  by a Plane for you and 2.I got some Books from India for you by a Plane. these sentence is also correct as describe above.

Comment: @D Manokhin Your sentence sounds strange. It would sound more idiomatic if it read: **I brought some apples for you from India** instead of **I took....** And your follow up sentences are not idiomatic: We say **by plane**, not *by a plane*. Although it's grammatically correct to say :**I got some books....**, it would sound more natural to say: **I brought some books...." The phrase **for you** fits in several places.